# Delete a file on a remote machine using bash script

Tags: bash, ssh, expect, delete-file

I want to basically copy files from remote machines, and after copying, delete them.

I have managed to copy the files using expect and scp.
Also, managed to delete the files outside of the script, but not able to use the ssh command inside the script.
This is what I have

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
log_user 1
set timeout -1
set pass "pass"


spawn scp  user@remote.machine.com:Desktop/LoginCheck/Login/* .
expect {
          password: {send "$pass\r" ; exp_continue}

}
ssh user@remote.machine.com 'rm -rf Desktop/LoginCheck/Login/*'
expect {
          password: {send "$pass\r" ; exp_continue}

}
```

So the `scp` section of code works.
But the `ssh` and `rm -rf`
this is the error for ssh

```
invalid command name "ssh"
    while executing
```

Can someone provide a working script?

Comment: Why are you using Expect for this?  It would be much safer to create a keypair, copy the public key to the remote host, and ssh and scp passwordless.

Comment: This script would need to work off multiple machines. (these multiple machines are various jenkins slave, I do not have access to create a key pair(thats a constraint for me)). Also, SSH in this script does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the ssh command be a new spawn?  By the way, just reading the [wikipedia article on expect](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect), one of the "cons" listed is:

> A less obvious argument against Expect is that it can enable
>   sub-optimal solutions. For example, a systems administrator needing to
>   log into multiple servers for automated changes might use Expect with
>   stored passwords, rather than the better solution of ssh agent keys.
>   The ability to automate interactive tools is attractive, but there are
>   frequently other options that can accomplish the same tasks in a more
>   robust manner.

Sounds like you're doing exactly the example sub-optimal solution.  If you were using a proper ssh key pair, you wouldn't need expect at all.

Comment: yes, adding the `spawn` did the trick, also changing the single inverted commas with double inverted commas. `ssh user@remote.machine.com "rm -rf Desktop/LoginCheck/Login/*"`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `ssh` with `spawn ssh` - `ssh` is not a built-in command of `expect`.

Answer (score 1):

You just missed the spawn in front of the ssh line:

```
spawn ssh user@remote.machine.com 'rm -rf Desktop/LoginCheck/Login/*'
```

You should also add a `wait` line before it, potentially checking for the exit code of scp.

In any case, don't use expect to automate ssh, use ssh keys and sh scripts like the other posters described.

Comment: You'd actually put `expect eof` as well as  `wait` before the next spawn